# How to Convert an HtmlTable cells to json object?

Tags: html, json

I need to frame a json object from an html table with all the cells in each rows of the table. i.e,

if my html table consists of 10 rows, 10 columns each for a row, i need to create a json object with all the 10 rows and the data within the 10 columns. How can this be possible with a json object?

Is it possible to save this big object to the db on a single click?

Help Please. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method:

```
function tableToJson(table) {
    var data = []; // first row needs to be headers var headers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
        headers[i] = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi, '');
    }
    // go through cells
    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        var tableRow = table.rows[i]; var rowData = {};
        for (var j = 0; j < tableRow.cells.length; j++) {
            rowData[headers[j]] = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML;
        } data.push(rowData);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Courtesy: http://johndyer.name/html-table-to-json/